# Error with position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get error:

ERROR: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer

What is the problem?

Comment: Is the type returned by `position` a struct by any chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `Transform.position` is `Vector3`, which is a struct. That means when you access it, you get a copy of the value. Then `ScreenToWorldPoint` takes that value and returns another `Vector3`. Mutating that value wouldn't do anything useful - it wouldn't change anything in the transform, which is presumably what you're trying to achieve. It sounds like you probably want something like:

```
var transform = GameObject.FindWithTag("Object").transform;
var position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(transform.position);
position.x -= 10;
transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(position);
```

Note the conversion back from world to screen co-ordinates, to keep everything in the original context.

Having written all of this, it should be noted that I've never done any Unity3d coding - this is just on the basis of regular C#.

Comment: And amazingly, this is 100% valid in the context of Unity. When I read the 'never done any Unity3D' coding I went back trying to look for some interpretative error, and found none. Not bad. :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just out of curiosity, when do you think you'll reach 1M reputation? Early 2018? :)

Comment: @Gog65: Some time in the second half of 2017, I think.